# $C^{1}$-curve is Lipschitz .

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am showing that a $C^{1}$ curve is Lipschitz . For this I considered $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

$\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),....,\gamma_n(t))$ is a $C^{1}-curve$ . To show it is Lipschitz , I will show $\| {\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)}\| \leq K|t-s|$ $\forall t,s \in [0,1]$   and $K>0$

$\|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)\|$= $ \|(\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(s),...,\gamma_n(t)-\gamma_n(s)\|$= $(|\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_1(s)|^{2},....,\gamma_n(t)-\gamma_n(s)|^{2})^{1/2}$.

How to proceed it , I will be thankful I someone can give me idea to proceed it .

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize the claim. It holds for any function $f$ that is $C^1$ on a compact set. A $C^1$ curve fulfills those requirements as the domain of a curve is a compact interval.

The proof for the case where $f$ is a function of only one variable:

If you assume that $f$ is **not** Lipschitz then you can create convergent sequences $s_n\to s$ and $t_n\to t$ such that $|f(s_n) - f(t_n)|>n|s_n - t_n|$. Since $f$ is continuous you can take this in limit and see that $s=t$. Now we have that

$$\left|{f(s_n) - f(t_n)\over s_n - t_n}\right| > n$$

which contradicts that $f$ is $C^1$ around $s=t$.

Comment: What is this $f$ you speak of? More importantly, have you forgotten such things as $x^2\sin(1/x^2)?$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I've straighten the requirement to be $C^1$ in order for the limit of the ratio to be the derivate. Your example is differentiable, but fails to be $C^1$ around $0$.  A tip is to get to the important point immediately and avoid start of with a rather stupid question: $f$ is of course a function that is (from now on) $C^1$ on a compact interval.

Comment: Still you have $f$ in there. And if $\gamma$ is $C^1$ you're not generalizing anything, right?

Comment: @zhw. Not much, but a compact set does not need to be an interval. With some modification we wouldn't require $f$ to be a function of only one variable either.